# How do I start a node with an anonymous name with roslaunch?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node that passes the following argument when calling `ros::init`:

```
ros::init_options::AnonymousName
```

It works fine and gives me a unique node name. However, when I launch this node from a roslaunch file, it does not create a unique node name anymore.

How do I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10608/how-do-i-start-a-node-with-an-anonymous-name-with-roslaunch?/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2011-07-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see: http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML

"
$(anon name)

e.g. $(anon rviz-1). Generates an anonymous id based on name. name itself is a unique identifier: multiple uses of $(anon foo) will create the same "anonymized" name. This is used for  name attributes in order to create nodes with anonymous names, as ROS requires nodes to have unique names.
"

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [F1iX](https://answers.ros.org/users/60271/f1ix/) on 2020-10-01**:
Is there a way to actually generate random ids/names then?